# How fix slow scrolling in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

need your help with slow scrolling in ListView. When I run my app and scrolling ListView it doing very slow with breaks.

Here's my **logcat**:

```
07-07 14:27:17.682  30190-30190/com.nadolskiy.sergey.githubreader I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-07 14:27:22.550  30190-30190/com.nadolskiy.sergey.githubreader I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 92 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-07 14:27:30.116  30190-30190/com.nadolskiy.sergey.githubreader I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 104 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-07 14:27:32.023  30190-30190/com.nadolskiy.sergey.githubreader I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 111 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-07 14:27:33.828  30190-30190/com.nadolskiy.sergey.githubreader I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 100 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

**custom_listview.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custom_listview_tv_repositoryName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Github-Reader"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/custom_listview_tv_languageLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Language: "
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/custom_listview_tv_language"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Java"
                android:textSize="14dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custom_listview_tv_branchCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="15"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="right" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/custom_listview_iv_branch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_branch"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custom_listview_tv_inFavoriteCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="31"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="right" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/custom_listview_iv_favorite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_star"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public Resources res;
ListModel tempValues = null;
int i = 0;
Typeface textFont;

public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList d, Resources resLocal) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    res = resLocal;
    textFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/DiamondGirl.ttf");

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (data.size() <= 0)
        return 1;
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView repositoryName;
    public TextView language;
    public TextView branchCount;
    public TextView inFavoriteCount;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.repositoryName  = (TextView) vi.findViewById(
                R.id.custom_listview_tv_repositoryName);
        holder.language        = (TextView) vi.findViewById(
                R.id.custom_listview_tv_language);
        holder.branchCount     = (TextView) vi.findViewById(
                R.id.custom_listview_tv_branchCount);
        holder.inFavoriteCount = (TextView) vi.findViewById(
                R.id.custom_listview_tv_inFavoriteCount);

        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }
        ;
    if (data.size() <= 0) {
        holder.repositoryName.setText("No Data");
    } else {
        tempValues = null;
        tempValues = (ListModel) data.get(position);

        holder.repositoryName.setText(tempValues.getRepositoryName());
        holder.language.setText(tempValues.getLanguage());
        holder.branchCount.setText(tempValues.getBranchCount());
        holder.inFavoriteCount.setText(tempValues.getInFavoriteCount());

        vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
    }

    holder.repositoryName.setTypeface(textFont);
    holder.language.setTypeface(textFont);
    holder.branchCount.setTypeface(textFont);
    holder.inFavoriteCount.setTypeface(textFont);

    return vi;
}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    Log.v("Custom Adapter", "Button Clicked");
}

private class OnItemClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    private int mPosition;

    OnItemClickListener(int position) {
        mPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        UserActivity ua = (UserActivity) activity;
        ua.onItemClick(mPosition);
    }
}
```

**ListModel.java**

```
public class ListModel {

private String repositoryName  = "";
private String language        = "";
private String branchCount     = "";
private String inFavoriteCount = "";

public void setRepositoryName(String repositoryName) {
    this.repositoryName = repositoryName;
}

public void setLanguage(String language) {
    this.language = language;
}

public void setBranchCount(String branchCount) {
    this.branchCount = branchCount;
}

public void setInFavoriteCount(String inFavoriteCount) {
    this.inFavoriteCount = inFavoriteCount;
}

public String getRepositoryName() {
    return repositoryName;
}

public String getLanguage() {
    return language;
}

public String getBranchCount() {
    return branchCount;
}

public String getInFavoriteCount() {
    return inFavoriteCount;
}
}
```

**UserActivity.java**

```
public class UserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView list;
    CustomAdapter adapter;
    public UserActivity userActivity = null;
    public ArrayList<ListModel> customListViewValuesArr = new ArrayList<ListModel>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

    userActivity = this;

    setListData();

    Resources res = getResources();
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activitu_user_lv_repositoriesList);

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(userActivity, customListViewValuesArr, res);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

    private void setListData() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            final ListModel sched = new ListModel();

            sched.setRepositoryName("Repository №" + i);
            sched.setLanguage("Java");
            sched.setBranchCount("" + (i+5));
            sched.setInFavoriteCount("" + (i*12));

            customListViewValuesArr.add(sched);
        }
    }

public void onItemClick(int mPosition) {
        ListModel tempValues = (ListModel) customListViewValuesArr.get(mPosition);

        Toast.makeText(userActivity, "" + tempValues.getRepositoryName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Thanks, =)

Comment: Try to run by commenting the custom font setup

Comment: @VaisakhN I tried, but didn't help.

Comment: Are you using android studio? If then go to memory monitor from Android Tab below there you can see allocated memory from there scroll your listview multiple times and let me know if the allocated memory increasing much more if not let me know which phone you are using

Comment: @VaisakhN yes, I use Android Studio, [link](http://postimg.org/image/5gnsev7k7/) - screen-shot of CPU, my device **Motorola Moto G (X1028)**

Comment: what about memory?4th tab

Comment: @VaisakhN in memory no difference when scrolling [link](http://s8.postimg.org/z0emb214l/image.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant find problem in this code and this is sad, but I find solution in [tutorial](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/android-custom-listview-example/). I rewrite my code and it helps. So, how it look now:

**CustomAdapter.java** rename to **RepositoryAdapter.java** and rewrite some code:

```
public class RepositoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
Typeface textFont;
protected List<Repository> listRepository;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public RepositoryAdapter(Context context, List<Repository> listRepository){
    this.listRepository = listRepository;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;

    textFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/DiamondGirl.ttf");
}

public int getCount(){
    return listRepository.size();
}

@Override
public Repository getItem(int position) {
    return listRepository.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview, parent, false);

        holder.tvRepositoryName =
                (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_listview_tv_repositoryName);
        holder.tvLanguage =
                (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_listview_tv_language);
        holder.tvBranchCount =
                (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_listview_tv_branchCount);
        holder.tvInFavoriteCount =
                (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_listview_tv_inFavoriteCount);

        holder.tvRepositoryName.setTypeface(textFont);
        holder.tvLanguage.setTypeface(textFont);
        holder.tvBranchCount.setTypeface(textFont);
        holder.tvInFavoriteCount.setTypeface(textFont);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Repository repository = listRepository.get(position);
    holder.tvRepositoryName.setText(repository.getRepositoryName());
    holder.tvLanguage.setText(repository.getLanguage());
    holder.tvBranchCount.setText(repository.getBranchCount());
    holder.tvInFavoriteCount.setText(repository.getInFavoriteCount());

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvRepositoryName;
    TextView tvLanguage;
    TextView tvBranchCount;
    TextView tvInFavoriteCount;
}

}
```

**ListModel.java** now **Repository.java**:

```
public class Repository {

private String repositoryName  = "";
private String language        = "";
private String branchCount     = "";
private String inFavoriteCount = "";

public Repository(String repositoryName, String language, String branchCount, String inFavoriteCount) {
    super();

    this.repositoryName  = repositoryName;
    this.language        = language;
    this.branchCount     = branchCount;
    this.inFavoriteCount = inFavoriteCount;
}

public void setRepositoryName(String repositoryName) {
    this.repositoryName = repositoryName;
}

public void setLanguage(String language) {
    this.language = language;
}

public void setBranchCount(String branchCount) {
    this.branchCount = branchCount;
}

public void setInFavoriteCount(String inFavoriteCount) {
    this.inFavoriteCount = inFavoriteCount;
}

public String getRepositoryName() {
    return repositoryName;
}

public String getLanguage() {
    return language;
}

public String getBranchCount() {
    return branchCount;
}

public String getInFavoriteCount() {
    return inFavoriteCount;
}
}
```

**UserActivity.java**:

```
public class UserActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
ArrayList<Repository> arrayRepositories;
ListView listViewRepositories;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

    arrayRepositories = new ArrayList<Repository>();

    fillList();

    listViewRepositories = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activitu_user_lv_repositoriesList);
    RepositoryAdapter adapter = new RepositoryAdapter(this, arrayRepositories);
    listViewRepositories.setAdapter(adapter);
    listViewRepositories.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
    Repository selectedRepository = arrayRepositories.get(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, selectedRepository.getRepositoryName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void fillList() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        Repository repository = new Repository("Repository #"+i,"Java",""+ (i*5),"" + (i*12));
        arrayRepositories.add(repository);
    }
}

}
```

Now it's works, and work fast. Thanks all for help =)

Answer (score 0):

Everything looking good to improve performance you can setTypeFace in first if block that is

```
if(convertview==null}
{



//at the end
    holder.repositoryName.setTypeface(textFont);
    holder.language.setTypeface(textFont);
    holder.branchCount.setTypeface(textFont);
    holder.inFavoriteCount.setTypeface(textFont);
}
```

Comment: can you edit your question and provide ListView tags in your activity.

Comment: @Mohd Mufiz: the message says "The application may be doing too much work on its **main thread.** " so it is likely that some operation has to go into a non-gui-background thread

Comment: @MohdMufiz sorry, but i don't understand what exactly you want, that i do?

Answer (score 0):

If scrolling is to slow it is likely that something in

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

is to slow.  getView is called for every list-item that becomes visible.

Is this the slow part that needs expensive database/file system query?

```
  tempValues = (ListModel) data.get(position);
```

I had the same problem with a list-view that contain images where calculating and caching the preview image from the original was expensive.

This can be solved using a [ui synchronized WorkerThread or AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads)

Comment: yes, i think problem in getView(), because when i comment tempValues it's work very fast. But all elements in listview the same.